# Ruby: search for a partial match in an inverted index

Tags: ruby, full-text-search

I need to search for a partial match in an inverted index, following code works for exact matches but not for partial. Reworked this from the example at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Inverted_Index (which no longer works in Ruby1.9.3)

How to do that the most efficient way please ?
Please no advise about using Lucene, Sphinx etc unless you know a lightweight, simple and pure Ruby solution, want to do it myself.

```
@data = {"contents"=>["1.txt", "2.txt"], "of"=>["1.txt", "2.txt"], "file"=>["1.txt", "2.txt"], "one"=>["1.txt"], "two"=>["2.txt"]}

def search words
  result = []
  words.each do |word|
    result << @data[word] if @data[word] #should do a partial match
  end
  result
end

p search ['of'] #=> [["1.txt", "2.txt"]]
p search ['one'] #=> [["1.txt"]]
p search ['on']  #=> []                    <<should become [["1.txt"]]
```

Comment: you can easily work out a O(1) algorithm (in time) for each word if you don't care for space; just build a hash with all the substrings as keys with the corresponding value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `search` as follows:

```
def search words
  words.map do |word|
    matches = @data.keys.select {|key| key.include?(word)}
    matches.map {|match| @data[match] }
  end      
end

p search ['of'] #=> [[["1.txt", "2.txt"]]]
p search ['one'] #=> [[["1.txt"]]]
p search ['on']  #=> [[["1.txt", "2.txt"], ["1.txt"]]] - note that "contents" contains "on"
```

Comment: probably the simplest way, but the not the most efficient. Note that `flat_map` will flatten those nested arrays.

Comment: thanks Chowlett, it's strange, i had to embed my arrays in parentheses like this p search(['of']) otherwise error <<can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)>>

Comment: @tokland, what would be more efficient ? care to also give an answer ?

Comment: @peter: see my comment above to the question for a O(1) solution. It's pretty easy to implement, just build a hash for all the substrings.